# Ternary operator usage with OR in subexpression in C#

Tags: c#

I understand standard usage of ternary operator..

```
string message = hasError=="Y" ? "There's an error!" : "Everything seems fine...";
```

But how do I add an OR in the subexpression..

```
if((hasError=="Y")||(seemsfine=="N")){
message="There's an error!";
}else{message="Everything seems fine...";
}
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
string message = hasError == "Y" || seemsfine == "N" ? "There's an error!" : "Everything seems fine...";
```

There is not much difference. This is because the ternary operator in C# ***is*** that handy!

Ultimately, it is the result of the whole expression (that is, `hasError == "Y" || seemsfine == "N"`) that matters, not how many conditions you have. You can put all other conditions if you want too, as long as the whole expression return `true` then it will assign the first element (left of `:`) to the variable and when the whole expression is `false` it assigns the second element (right of `:`) to the variable

Ternary operator is **completely equivalent** with if-else statement whose block is simply to **assign value to single variable**.

Thus,

```
if (a1 == 0 || a2 > 5 || a3 <= -7)
    b = 1;
else
    b = 2;
```

is completely equivalent to

```
b = a1 == 0 || a2 > 5 || a3 <= -7 ? 1 : 2; //note that there is no bracket here, but it is equivalent to if-else statement with bracket
```

When you have **more** than single variable to be assigned, then the equivalent **breaks**.

```
if (a1 >= 0)
    b = 2;
else
    c = 3; //notice the variable difference, you cannot use ternary operator anymore.
```

As long as it does not hinder the readability of the code for you, you can even put multiple ternary operators like this

```
b = a1 > 0 && a2 < 0 ? 1 : (a3 < 5 ? 2 : 3);
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (a1 > 0 && a2 < 0)
    b = 1;
else if (a3 < 5)
    b = 2;
else
    b = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

The initial expression can be as simple or as complicated as you need it to be, as long as the condition ultimately evaluates to a single boolean value, just like the first line of your `if` statement.

In other words, this:

```
if ((hasError == "Y") || (seemsfine == "N"))
    message="There's an error!";
else
    message="Everything seems fine...";
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
string message = (hasError == "Y" || seemsfine == "N")
    ? "There's an error!"
    : "Everything seems fine...";
```